# How to delete graph edges with specified weights?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I wonder, if it's possible to delete graph edges on the base of their weights.
In other words, can patterns in the function `EdgeDelete[g,patt]` include weights of edges to delete? WM Documentation doesn't describe these options.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the pattern

```
_?(yourCondition @ PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight] &)
```

or the pattern

```
e_ /; (yourCondition @ PropertyValue[{g, e}, EdgeWeight]
```

***Examples:***

```
g1 = CompleteGraph[4, EdgeWeight -> Range[6], 
  VertexLabels -> Automatic, EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"]
```

[image]

```
g2 = EdgeDelete[g1, _?(OddQ @ PropertyValue[{g1, #}, EdgeWeight] &)];

(* or g2 = EdgeDelete[g1, e_ /; (OddQ @ PropertyValue[{g1, e}, EdgeWeight])]; *)

Graph[g2, VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[g1]]
```

[image]

```
forbiddenweights = {1, 3, 4};

g3 = EdgeDelete[g1, _?(MatchQ[Alternatives @@ forbiddenweights]@
      PropertyValue[{g1, #}, EdgeWeight] &)];

Graph[g3, VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[g1]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this should help!